# Homology of non-singular projective algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, proof-verification, homology-cohomology

I am unsure whether or not the following claim is true or false and whether or not my proof works or not:

**Claim:** Let $V \subset \mathbb{C}P^n$ be a complex $k$-dimensional, non-singular, projective algebraic variety.
Then for all $i > k$ the homology groups are $H_i(V)=0$.

Is the following proof correct?

**My proof:** It can be shown that $V$ is induced by a $k$-dimensional manifold $\bar{V} \subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, i.e. $V = q(\bar{V})$, where $q: \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ is the quotient map. 
Because of the properties of the quotient map $q$, we can choose $\bar{V} \subset S^n$, where $S^n \subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ is the $n$-sphere.
From Theorem 7.1 in John Milnor's book "Morse Theory" it follows that for all $i > k$ we have $H_i(\bar{V})=0.$

Consider the map $p: V \rightarrow \bar{V}$ that sends an equivalence class $[x] \in V$ to $p(x) := \frac{x}{|x|} \in \bar{V}$.
The composition of this map with $q$ is the identity on $V$, i.e. $q \circ p = id$.
Hence the induced maps in homology give $q_* \circ p_* =id$, therefore:
$$q_* \circ p_* =id: H_i(V) \stackrel{p_*}{\rightarrow} \underbrace{H_i(\bar{V})}_{=0 \text{, if } i>k} \stackrel{q_*}{\rightarrow} H_i(V)$$
and it follows that $H_i(V)=0$ for all $i > k$.

Comment: You are confusing real and complex dimension. For instance, $\mathbf P^1$ is a 1-dimensional algebraic variety, but it has $H_2 \cong \mathbf Z$. If you replace $k$ by $2k$ in your claim, it becomes true.